# user_passes_test for models other than User in Django

Tags: python, django, permissions

I want to allow a user to edit a project page if ifAdmin (an object in uProject model) == True. I am currently trying to use @user_passes_test to render a view to update the project, but am having difficulties. I am getting uProjects from main.models, and I am working in projects.views. Here's my code.

```
def admin_check(uProjects):
    return uProjects.ifAdmin = True

@user_passes_test(admin_check)
def update(request): etc, etc, etc
```

models.py

```
class uProjects(models.Model):
   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ifAccepted = models.BooleanField(null = True, blank=False, default=False)
    #ifLeader = models.BooleanField(null = False, blank=False)
    ifAdmin = models.BooleanField(null = True, blank=False, default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ',' + self.project.name
```

The difficulty is I'm trying to have admin_check work with uProjects, not the User model. I'm also trying to see if ifAdmin == True, but the way I did above renders an error. The error is that the "User object has no attribute ifAdmin"

Comment: Please elaborate a bit, what are the difficulties...??

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha the difficulty is I'm trying to have admin_check work with uProjects, not the User model. I'm also trying to see if ifAdmin == True, but the way I did above renders an error. The error is that the "User object has no attribute ifAdmin"

Comment: can you please share the models?

Comment: @ruddra I just edited the main post and added it there

Comment: @JoaoAlmeida-Domingues sorry, I just updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewBregman you are doing `uProjects.ifAdmin = True` not `uProjects.ifAdmin == True`

Comment: Please also update the question from where are you getting `uProjects`...

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha I just updated it to "==" but am still getting the same error. I've also updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
def admin_check(user):
    return user.uprojects_set.filter(ifAdmin=True).exists()

@user_passes_test(admin_check)
def update(request): etc, etc, etc
```

But this will work for any user which has ifAdmin permission in atleast one uProject instance. It can't distinguish by uProject information.

To do that, you can write a custom dectorator like this:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def admin_check(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        name = kwargs.get('name')  # assuming you are getting the project id here via url: "/<project_id:int>"
        if uProjects.objects.filter(title=name, user=user, ifAdmin=True).exists():
             return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

  return wrap
```

Comment: thank you for the great response. For this code: ```def admin_check(user):
    return user.uproject_set.filter(ifAdmin=True).exists()

@user_passes_test(admin_check)
def update(request): etc, etc, etc``` I am still running into an error because user has no attribute uproject_set. I think this may be because user is a part of uProjects, but uProjects is not a subsection of user, if that makes sense.

Comment: for the second code, my url is for the project name as follows: ```path('project/<str:name>/', p.project, name='project'),``` I also have a quick question on the second code. When returning the function, how do I correlate this with the view the edit the project page?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have updated both of the code snippets.

Comment: Thank you. For these code snippets, when I go to run my code, even though the user I am logged in with has ifAdmin = True in the uProjects model, when I go to click on edit project, it returns the HttpResponseRedirect('/'), instead of letting me edit the project.

Comment: here is the code: ```def admin_check(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        name = kwargs.get('name')  
        if uProjects.objects.filter(title=name, user=user, ifAdmin=True).exists():
             return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

  return wrap

@admin_check
def update(request): etc etc```